# Assembly Syscalls in 64-bit Windows

Tags: windows, assembly, x86-64, system-calls, interrupt

I am on windows 10, with Cygwin installed. I have been using Cygwin for the compilation/assembly of c and assembly programs using Cygwin-installed "gcc" and "nasm". From what I know, nasm has a -f win64 mode, so it can assemble 64-bit programs. Now, for x64 assembly programming on windows, it seems youtube has a lack of tutorials. Most assembly programming tutorials on youtube are either for x64 linux or x32 windows, and I need to be able to print a string to the console on x64 windows, without the use of any external functions such as C's "printf".

StackOverflow links that didn't work for me:

[64-bit windows assembler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708502/64-bit-windows-assembler)

As far as I know, nasm does support 64-bit windows using the -f win64 extension. Also, the answers have nothing to do with how to write an actual program in assembly on x64 bit windows

[How to write hello world in assembler under Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023593/how-to-write-hello-world-in-assembler-under-windows)

All answers that give code give only code for outdated windows versions (32-bit), except one. The one answer that works for 64 bit I tried, but the command to link the object file gave an error for me, that the system could not find the path specified.

[windows x64 assembler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15145357/windows-x64-assembler)

This site does not contain any code, which is what I need. Also, I am trying to write the Hello World program in nasm.

[64 bit assembly, when to use smaller size registers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6577458/64-bit-assembly-when-to-use-smaller-size-registers)

The question actually contains code for a hello world program, but when executed under cygwin on windows 10 (my device), I get a segmentation fault.

[Why does Windows64 use a different calling convention from all other OSes on x86-64?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429398/why-does-windows64-use-a-different-calling-convention-from-all-other-oses-on-x86?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I have tried disassembling a C Hello World Program with objdump -d, but this calls printf, a prebuilt C function, and I am trying to avoid using external functions.

I have tried other external functions (such as Messagebox), but they return errors because something does not recognize the functions. Also, I am trying not to use any extern functions if possible, only syscall, sysenter, or interrupts.

CODE:

Attempt #1:

```
    section .data
    msg db "Hello, World!", 10, 0
    section .text
    mov rax, 1
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, msg
    mov rdx, 14
    syscall
    mov rax, 60
    mov rdi, 0
    syscall
```

Problem: Assembles and links properly, but throws a segmentation fault when run.

Attempt #2:

```
    section .text
    mov ah, 0eh
    mov al, '!', 0
    mov bh, 0
    mov bl, 0
    int 10h
```

Problem: Does not assemble properly; says "test.asm:3: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands"

Attempt #3:

```
    section .text
    msg db 'test', 10, 0
    mov rdi, 1
    mov rsi, 1
    mov rdx, msg
    mov rcx, 5
    syscall
    mov rdi, 60
    mov rsi, 0
    syscall
```

Problem: Assembles and links properly, but throws a segmentation fault when run.

Attempt #4:

```
    section .text
    mov ah, 0eh
    mov al, '!'
    mov bh, 0
    mov bl, 0
    int 10h
```

Problem: Assembles and links properly, but throws a segmentation fault when run.

I just need an example of a hello world assembly program that works on 64-bit Windows 10. 32-bit programs seem to return errors when I run them. If it is not possible to print a string to the console without using external functions, an example of a program that uses external functions and works on 64-bit Windows 10 would be nice.

I heard that syscalls in windows have far different addresses than those in linux.

Comment: [This MASMForum link](http://masm32.com/board/index.php?topic=6486.0) will help you. It is the key to the best MASM64 Windows source available.

Comment: Attempt 2 is 16bit DOS code, will not work as windows executable, and `mov al,imm8` instruction can contain only single 8 bit immediate value, so you have to pick if you want number `'!'` (`33` IIRC ASCII table) or number `0`, you can't assign to register `al` both at the same time. Attemp 3: unless you specify with some label where the code starts, it may start at the beginning of `.text` section, executing string data "test" as instructions (too lazy to check what kind of instructions they form). Labels like `_start:` are often used in cooperation with linker to specify entry point into code

Comment: Attemp 4 is again 16 bit DOS code (using BIOS interrupt `int 10h`), so you can use this one under some DOS emulator/VM, like dosbox. .. (and I guess attempt 1 and 3 are using linux or OSX syscalls, but I don't know how windows 64b system calls work, so I wouldn't recognize even correct way, I use only linux for last decade and sometimes DOS in dosbox)

Comment: Is there a special flag to set with ld to specify where the start of the program is? I tried putting _start in there and putting the message within section .data and it still says "Illegal instruction", so I am assuming that ld still doesn't know where to start.

Comment: This question looks a little like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41622071/2189500).

Comment: Oh, can someone give an example of using external functions then or a system dll to perform the operation of a simple syscall like write? Interesting that microsoft doesn't publish its own syscalls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Attempt #1:
>
> Attempt #2:

Internally Windows uses either interrupts or system calls. However they are not officially documented and they may change **anytime Microsoft wants to change them**:

Only a few `.dll` files directly use the system call instructions; all programs are directly or indirectly accessing these `.dll` files.

A certain sequence (for example `mov rax, 5`, `syscall`) might have the meaning "print out a text" before a Windows update and Microsoft might change the meaning of this sequence to "delete a file" after a Windows update.

To do this Microsoft simply has to replace the kernel and the `.dll` files which are officially "allowed" to use the `syscall` instruction.

The only way to call Windows operating system functions in a way that it is guaranteed that your program is still working after the next Windows update is to call the functions in the `.dll` files - just the same way you would do this in a C program.

Example (32-bit code):

```
push 1
push msg
push 14
call _write
mov dword [esp], 0
call _exit
```

Comment: The author requested 64 bit code. Is the C-level Windows API in x86_64 still a 32 bit interface? Which DLL's provide `_write` and `_exit`?

Comment: @mcandre The main aspect of my answer was the "platform independent" part: Directly using system calls will not work. The x86_32 example code is only there to make the last part of the answer clearer and not to give a "valid" example of code.

Comment: Been a while since I posted this, but I figured out which dll files to use and how to include them. C:\\Windows\\System32\\msvcrt.dll seems to provide the entire C standard library, and all you have to do is say "extern [whatever C function]" and link msvcrt.dll with your object file. It doesn't use syscalls, but considering what you said about syscalls in windows being unstable, I'm okay with using C's standard library in assembly. That's likely the only way to make it platform independent anyhow.

Comment: Just 1 question: do you know if there are in fact lower level dll files I could be using in place of msvcrt.dll? The fact that sizeof in C varies from implementation to implementation somewhat concerns me. I found user32.dll and kernel32.dll in System32, do these provide the windows library?

Comment: solved my own problem. there's a thing that comes with Visual Studio called dumpbin that, with /exports, allows you to see all functions that come with a .dll file. And it turns out that kernel32.dll does indeed provide the windows api.

Comment: Syscalls numbers indeed change: https://hfiref0x.github.io/syscalls.html but the question is an excersise in reverse engineering and not normal code.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at ReactOS source code. This Program is using Native API to print **Hello, world!\n** to console.

```cc
const char *Message = "Hello, world!\n";
HANDLE hStdOut = NtCurrentPeb()->ProcessParameter->StandardOutput;
IO_STATUS_BLOCK IoStatusBlock;
NtWriteFile(hStdout,
            NULL, 
            NULL, 
            NULL, 
            &IoStatusBlock, 
            (PVOID)Message,
            sizeof(Message),
            NULL,
            NULL);
// NtTerminateProcess(NtCurrentProcess(), STATUS_SUCCESS);
RtlExitUserProcess(STATUS_SUCCESS);
```

```assembly
extern NtWriteFile
; extern NtTerminateProcess
extern RtlExitUserProcess

%define NtCurrentPeb() gs:[0x60]
%define ProcessParameter 32
%define StandardOutput 40
%define NtCurrentProcess() -1

section .rdata
        Message db `Hello, world!\n\0`
        Length equ $-Message
section .text
        global main
main:
        sub rsp, 88
        mov rcx, NtCurrentPeb()
        mov rcx, ProcessParameter[rcx]
        mov rcx, StandardOutput[rcx]
        xor edx, edx
        xor r8d, r8d
        xor r9d, r9d
        lea rax, 72[rsp] ; IoStatusBlock
        mov qword 32[rsp], rax
        mov qword 40[rsp], Message
        mov qword 48[rsp], Length
        mov qword 56[rsp], 0
        mov qword 64[rsp], 0
        call NtWriteFile

        // mov rcx, NtCurrentProcess()
        // xor edx, edx
        // call NtTerminateProcess
        xor ecx, ecx
        call RtlExitUserProcess
        int3
```

## Explanation

First we extract `StandardOutput` handle by accessing `_RTL_USER_PARAMETERS` from `PEB`.
This is `hStdout` returned from `GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);`

call `NtWriteFile` to write into `StandardOutput` handle.
`WriteFile` call `NtWriteFile`.

`WriteConsole*` call `NtDeviceIoControlFile`.

the `NtDeviceIoControlFile` is more complex than `NtWriteFile` calls.

call `RtlExitUserProcess` to exit.
Actually we can just do `TerminateProcess(GetCurrentProcess(), ERROR_SUCCESS);` rather than `ExitProcess(ERROR_SUCCESS);`.
The second one is much safer, it does cleanup before Terminate self process. 
 `Rtl` is not system call, it stands for RunTimeLibrary.
It's extended C lib. 
It calls `NtTerminateProcess` inside that similar to `kill()`, Nt never had `exit_group()` similar system call.

### Calling Convention

`syscall` instruction clobber `R11`for rflags  and `RCX` for `RIP` so the first argument is on `R10`.

| System Call Number | Arg0 | Arg1 | Arg2 | Arg3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| RAX | R10 | RDX | R8 | R9 |

About the stack argument, it's started from `40[rsp]` due to shadow store (32 bytes), and 8 bytes from `call` instruction.

So if you want libc-free program. You can change from `RCX` to `R10`, pass the stack argument from `40[rsp]`, and `call NtXxx` to `mov eax, SYSCALL_NR`.

This program is stil depends on `ntdll.dll` because NT never had a stable system call number.

### Compability

May work from Windows 8 and above. See https://www.mandiant.com/resources/blog/monitoring-windows-console-activity-part-one

Comment: The `syscall` instruction itself clobbers RCX, but the DLL interface like `call NtWriteFile` still follows the function-calling convention, with the first arg in RCX.  That's what your example shows.  (The DLL function probably does `mov eax, call_number` / `mov r10, rcx` / `syscall` / `ret` and maybe some other library shenanigans, same as on Linux with libc wrapper functions for system calls.)  So you'd only need to care about the special calling convention if you were inlining `syscall` manually, with the unstable call number from https://j00ru.vexillium.org/syscalls/nt/64/

Comment: Ah thanks, edited. Also Windows Internals structure may changed on alter version. see https://ntdiff.github.io/